# Routing from any path to same files in express, nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I want to be able to send the same files for different paths like /stuff and /stuff/foo, the problem is that when I do try to do this I'm getting the following error:

```
Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8000/stuff/main.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Here is the code:

```
app.use("/", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "./../public")));
app.get("/stuff", sendIndexHTML);
app.get("/stuff/:id", sendIndexHTML);

function sendIndexHTML(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "./../public/index.html"));
}
```

Comment: is your app an SPA ?

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix It's a react-app using react-router

Comment: why not handle the routing in client side? you already use react-router, and basically you render the same page.

Comment: If you want to go to /foo you shouldnt have to navigate through the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're referencing `main.js` in your `index.html` as a relative path so it's getting served from `/stuff`, which that path is set up to return `index.html` (which has a mime type `text/html`).

What you need to do is update the script file path in your html file.

change

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="/main.js"></script>
```

that way it is served from the root path which is configured to serve static assets.